# Loop for two functions

Tags: r

I have a function that calculates the minimun simple size required for a certain confidence interval a given sample size and a given margin of error based on a given confidence level.

```
x<-c(1,-2,3,-4,5,-6,7,-8,9,-8,9,-8,7,-6,5,-4,3,-2,1,-0,1,-2,3,-4,5,-6,7,-8,9,-0,1,-2,3,-4,5,-6,7,-8,9,0,1,-2,3,-4,5,-6,7,-8,9)


 T <-sum( x > 0  )/length(x)
 sample.size = function(c.lev, margin=T,
                       c.interval=.1, population) {
  z.val = qnorm(T+c.lev/ 200)
  ss = (z.val^2 * margin * (1-margin))/c.interval^2
  p.ss = round((ss/(1 + ((ss-1)/population))), digits=0)
  METHOD = paste("Recommended sample size for a population of ",
                 population, " at a ", c.lev,
                 "% confidence level", sep = "")
  structure(list(Population = population,
                 "Confidence level" = c.lev,
                 "Margin of error" = c.interval,
                 "Response distribution" = margin,
                 "Recommended sample size" = p.ss,
                 method = METHOD),
            class = "power.htest")
        }
        e<-sample.size(y, , , length(x))
```

I would like to loop `e` for a range of `y` (confidence level) and select the value that produces the highest confidence level, sequencing by 1 down from 100 to 0 and selecting (stop the loop) at the confidence level `y` value prior to the `y` value that yields  `e[[5]]!= NaN` and selecting that value.

Thank you

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: You can use `mapply`.